# Merge rows with same name column and concatenate occasion column

Tags: mysql

I have a table with many rows that have a duplicate name . I want to merge these rows into one, and concatenate the occasion column values that are different separated by a comma (,)

So in the following example, row 2191 would have the occasion value: christmas, hannukah, just because, and the duplicate rows would be removed.

```
ID      name                            url                                                     amazon                                                  image                                                   price   relationship                                    occasion                                                    

2191    Bake & Decorate Cupcake Set     http://www.kqzyfj.com/click-7602811-10971062?url=h...   http://amzn.to/1pi7KO2                                  http://www.lduhtrp.net/image-7602811-10971062?imgu...   0.00    sister, daughter, granddaughter, niece, friend  christmas 
4517    Bake & Decorate Cupcake Set     http://www.kqzyfj.com/click-7602811-10971062?url=h...   http://amzn.to/1pi7KO2                                  http://www.lduhtrp.net/image-7602811-10971062?imgu...   0.00    sister, daughter, granddaughter, niece, friend  hannukah 
5902    Bake & Decorate Cupcake Set     http://www.kqzyfj.com/click-7602811-10971062?url=h...   http://amzn.to/1pi7KO2                                  http://www.lduhtrp.net/image-7602811-10971062?imgu...   0.00    sister, daughter, granddaughter, niece, friend  just because    
1660    Ballerina Treasure Music Box    http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B000FGKDLK/ref=as...   http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B000FGKDLK/ref=as...   http://ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?_encodi...   25.99   sister, daughter, granddaughter, niece, friend  birthday    
2798    Ballerina Treasure Music Box    http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B000FGKDLK/ref=as...   http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B000FGKDLK/ref=as...   http://ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?_encodi...   25.99   sister, daughter, granddaughter, niece, friend  christmas   
5155    Ballerina Treasure Music Box    http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B000FGKDLK/ref=as...   http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B000FGKDLK/ref=as...   http://ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?_encodi...   25.99   sister, daughter, granddaughter, niece, friend  hannukah
```

Comment: Can you show us the query you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

It is a little hard to tell exactly what the query is, but the path you want to go down is aggregation and `group_concat()`:

```
select min(id) as id, name, group_concat(occasion separator ', ')
from table t
group by name;
```

It is unclear what other columns you might want in the output.